# Calendar App in Android 4.4.2 does not create events in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, calendar

I am trying to add and view events in my calendar in android emulator(API 19).
When I double click on a particular date, I get the following dialogue box with message:

**"Before you can add an event you must at least add a calendar account..."**

Even after adding accounts by going to settings-> add account -> IMAP , I am still not able to 
add or view events. Though my gmail account is shown to be synced, I am not able to view events in the emulator calendar. I have been struggling both issues for 2 days now.

I also followed this link http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-a-google-account-in-the-emulator/ but could not solve the issue

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but is this a programming question?

Comment: This question is not a programming question and should be asked on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Open the calendar on the emulator first, let the calender cause sync so it has a data set to work with, however if you building an app like this you should really be building an a device so it more like the real use, as calendar app syncs with all it can Gmail/Exchange and more if you add them

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

First sign in with your gmail account, next

Just go to apps > calendar storage and clear data 
Go back > calendar and clear data 
Then open calendar app... it will ask to sign in, just press home (don't sign in)

After a couple of minutes your entries would appear and you'll be able to edit.

Don't know if its a temp solution or permanent.